# Dynamically link images to actual files

Tags: powerpoint

Right now, when I insert an image into a slide, powerpoint keeps a copy of it and doesn't change the image when the parent file on disk changes.

How do I link an image to the file on disk so that everytime I change the file, the corresponding image in the slide also changes.

Comment: @Will: Sorry to bother you again (you also closed my other question)... where should questions of this kind go? I see a lot of questions like this in the powerpoint tag.

Comment: StackOverflow is for *programming related questions only*.  You can ask general computer related questions on [superuser](http://superuser.com).  Check out that StackExchange dropdown at the top left, we have lots of different websites that cover many different subjects.  Also, if you do see questions like this, *please flag them for moderator attention*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [PPT and Images](http://classes.yale.edu/help/itools/Powerpoint/images_ppt.htm):

> Add a link to an image file:
>
> If you link to an image file rather
>   than embed the image, any changes made
>   to the original file will be reflected
>   in the presentation.
>
> Click in the slide where the linked
>   object or embedded object will be
>   placed.
>
> On the Insert menu, click Object.
>
> Click Create from file.
>
> In the File box, type the name of the
>   file, or click Browse to select from a
>   list.
>
> To create a linked object, select the
>   Link check box. (An embedded object is
>   created if you don't select the Link
>   check box.)
>
> To display the linked object or
>   embedded object as an icon — for
>   example, if others are going to view
>   the file online — select the Display
>   as icon check box.

Comment: this works... but does anyone know if there is a faster way to do this? I don't know, maybe like alt-drag or something.

Comment: watch out for image url that are too long

Answer (score 24):

Creating an object is the heavyweight way to do things, or can be.
Instead:
Use PowerPoint's Insert, Picture, From File command.
Browse to the picture you want to insert.
To the right of the Insert button there's a downward arrowhead. Click that.

Now depending on your PPT version, you'll see two or three options.  Once is a straight link.  That'll produce a link to the image file that'll update whenever you open the presentation and PPT finds that the image has changed.  And unless you take special steps, the link will break if you move the file, leaving you with a red x instead of an image.

Recommended:
If you have 2007 or later, there's a Link + Embed option.  That embeds the image in the presentation file (no broken links/red Xs) but still checks the original to see if the embedded image needs updating.

Comment: This works. Is it possible to update the powerpoint slide without closing and opening powerpoint? Something like the F5 command when updating an internet browser.

Comment: The minimum in PowerPoint 2007 seems to be to start and stop the slide show, switch to Slide Sorter view then back to Normal; the status bar buttons are handy for this. A more explicit way is Start | Prepare | Edit Links to Files (you'll need to scroll down to see this!) | select the file link, Update Now, Close.

Comment: This does result in security warnings when the .pptx file is copied to another PC. The warnings can be ignored, but it might result in worries for some overly-nervous recipients.

Comment: Link+embed is amazing. I can't believe I never knew about this feature. Thank you so much.